# Bind dictionary of a class to data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, dictionary

I have the following class that I want to bind it's dictionary's value to a data grid control

```
public class DBRow : IEnumerable<DBColumn>
{
    public DBColumn this[string ColumnName]
    {
        get { return Columns[ColumnName]; }
        set { Columns[ColumnName] = value; }
    }
    public Dictionary<string, DBColumn> Columns { get; set; }

    public DBRow()
    {
        this.Columns = new Dictionary<string, DBColumn>();
    }

    public List<KeyValuePair<string,DBColumn>> GetKeysPair()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, DBColumn>> ListOfKeyPair = new List<KeyValuePair<string, DBColumn>>();
        foreach (var KeyPair in Columns)
        {
            ListOfKeyPair.Add(KeyPair);
        }
        return ListOfKeyPair;
    }

    public void AddColumn(DBColumn Column)
    {
        Columns.Add(Column.Name, Column);
    }
    public IEnumerator<DBColumn> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var Column in Columns)
        {
            yield return Column.Value;
        }
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in Columns)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

using foreach on the

```
GetKeysPair() method
```

I try to bind it like this:

```
    foreach (var item in Row.GetKeysPair())
        {
            DataGridTextColumn DataGridColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
            DataGridColumn.Header = item.Value.Name;

            DataGridColumn.Binding = new Binding(********); <<---  Problem!!             

            dataGridDataList.Columns.Add(DataGridColumn); <<--- DataGrid
        }
```

Problem is that i don't know what to type in

```
New Binding(string);
```

I am trying to bind the following property:

```
public struct DBColumn
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

I tried alot of options but i just cant manage to figure it out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I assumed the ItemsSource of your DataGrid is a collection of dictionaries (or a collection of list<keyvaluepair>), if this is the case then I believe you should be able to just use the indexer to access the value, e.g.

```
DataGridColumn.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}].Data", item.Key));
```

Comment: WOW, Thanks for that. it actually worked.  I spent about 3 hours on that damn line and for some reason i just couldn't see the simple answer :D thank you very much